# How to get audacity to recognize audio input without suspending pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio, audacity

I'm facing the issue that..

```
$ audacity
```

..starts audacity, but with missing inputs.

```
$ pasuspender -- audacity
```

..starts audacity with all my inputs restored, so I can record from line-in, but then I cannot listen to music while doing so and there's some other strange behavior when trying to playback what I recorded. In some parts the audio gets extremely loud and then back to normal. So it's not even a viable workaround.

All of this worked without problems on the same hardware before I upgrade from Linux Mint 19 to Linux Mint 20

```
Audacity v2.3.3

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.3
Release:    20.3
Codename:   una

$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa"
```

Comment: I haven't figured it out until this day and audacity remains broken in this way.